# Combine separate SQL queries together filling in the blanks

Tags: sql

I am trying to create an SQL query that combines the results of 3 queries together.

The idea is get the top 1000 users with new messages AND/OR requests AND/OR notifications and then email them one per week.

Note: I am using MS SQL Server.

I have 3 separate complex queries (which i have simplified here) such as:

```
'Get all users with new messages:
SELECT mbrid, messageCount
FROM tblMessages
WHERE messageCount > 0

'Get all users with new notifications:
SELECT mbrid, notificationCount
FROM tblNotifications
WHERE notificationCount > 0

'Get all users with new requests:
SELECT mbrid, requestCount
FROM tblRequests
WHERE requestCount > 0
```

I want to combine all 3 together into 1 table, and select the TOP 1000 records.

### For example

If each query returns:

```
mbrID    messageCount
---------------------
2        20
3        2

mbrID    notificationCount
---------------------
1        1
3        2

mbrID    requestCount
---------------------
3        2
```

I want to combine the 3 results to create a table like so:

```
mbrID    messageCount    notificationCount    requestCount
----------------------------------------------------------
1        0               1                    0
2        20              0                    0
3        2               2                    2
```

Notice that the combined results should fill in the missing rows with blanks eg: 0

Is this even possible?

If there are millions of records, I guess this would be incredibly inefficient.
Any pointers to do this a better way?

### Update

Here is what I finally chose (@Upendra Chaudhari solution), 
thanks to everyone for your help.

```
SELECT TOP (1000)
    mbrID, 
    SUM(messageCount) AS messageCount, 
    SUM(notificationCount) AS notificationCount, 
    SUM(requestCount) AS requestCount 
FROM (

    SELECT TOP (1000)
            mbrID,
            messageCount,
            0 AS notificationCount,
            0 AS requestCount
    FROM 
            usrv_CommMessagesNew
    ORDER BY
            mbrID

    UNION

    SELECT TOP (1000)
            mbrID,
            0 AS messageCount,
            notificationCount,
            0 AS requestCount
    FROM 
            usrv_CommNotificationsNew
    ORDER BY
            mbrID

    UNION

    SELECT TOP (1000)
            mbrID,
            0 AS messageCount,
            0 AS notificationCount,
            requestCount
    FROM 
            usrv_CommRequestsNew
    ORDER BY
            mbrID

    ) AS tblTemp

GROUP BY
    mbrID
```

The TOP 1000 clause limits the results to improve performance.

Due to this, messageCount takes first priority followed by notificationCount then requestCount.

This means that the data may not include all rows for notificationCount or requestCount - I am fine with that in this instance - it is optimised for performance over consistency.

Comment: Have you tried with UNION?

Comment: Use COALESCE like I said in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try UNION like this :

```
    SELECT  mbrid, SUM(messageCount), SUM(notificationCount), SUM(requestCount)
FROM    (
            SELECT mbrid, messageCount, 0 AS notificationCount, 0 AS requestCount
            FROM tblMessages
            WHERE messageCount > 0

            UNION

            SELECT mbrid, 0 AS messageCount, notificationCount, 0 AS requestCount
            FROM tblNotifications
            WHERE notificationCount > 0

            UNION

            SELECT mbrid, 0 AS messageCount, 0 AS notificationCount, requestCount
            FROM tblRequests
            WHERE requestCount > 0
        ) TempTable
GROUP BY mbrid
```

Comment: this looked promising but the UNION clumps everything into the first column

Comment: @geo1701 what do you mean by clumps everything into the first column?  Ive just replicated the data above and ran the query the results were as you have asked for.

Comment: You are correct, your method does work well. UNION is better than JOIN - I will evaluate on real data and get back to you! thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, once you "union" all three tables together, how are you going to decide which records are the top 1000?

If your intention is to treat messages, notifications and requests similarly, then the following may be the answer you are looking for:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM
(SELECT mbrid, messageCount as Count
FROM tblMessages
WHERE messageCount > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT mbrid, notificationCount as Count
FROM tblNotifications
WHERE notificationCount > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT mbrid, requestCount as Count
FROM tblRequests
WHERE requestCount > 0
ORDER BY Count DESC) d
```

For more information regarding the UNION and UNION ALL operators, see [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29#UNION_operator).

Comment: He want all counts in different columns, not in single column.

Comment: UNION clumps everything into 1 column

Comment: @UpendraChaudhari I realize that this is what the question states. However, it also states that the intention is to select the top 1000 rows from the resulting table. Which means that there will need to exist some criteria by which to sort the results. This was a simply a suggestion of how this could be achieved.

Comment: See 'Update' in question on how I ended up selecting the TOP 1000. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `COALESCE` if you want to use `OUTER JOIN`, this should be OK:

```
SELECT COALESCE(m.mbrid, r.mbrid, n.mbrid) AS mbrid, ISNULL(m.messageCount,0) AS messageCount, ISNULL(n.NotificationCount,0) AS NotificationCount, ISNULL(r.requestCount, 0) AS requestCount
FROM tblMessages m
FULL JOIN tblNotifications n
    ON m.mbrid = n.mbrid
    AND m.messageCount > 0
    AND n.notificationCount > 0
FULL JOIN tblRequests r
    ON m.mbrid = r.mbrid
    AND r.requestCount > 0  
ORDER BY mbrid
```

cause returns exactly what you want:

```
| MBRID | MESSAGECOUNT | NOTIFICATIONCOUNT | REQUESTCOUNT |
|-------|--------------|-------------------|--------------|
|     1 |            0 |                 1 |            0 |
|     2 |           20 |                 0 |            0 |
|     3 |            2 |                 2 |            2 |
```

as you can see [here](http://pastebin.com/jK8cA0tb).

Comment: A Union All would be faster than joining the tables. If there are millions of records this could well make a big difference.

Comment: UNION All would clump everything into 1 column

Comment: While this works well, I am getting multiple rows with the same mbrid. Using DISTINCT doesnt seem to correct either.

Comment: Try to make a Fiddle.